# Parallel association rule mining

Tags: data-mining, association-rules, parallel-computing

I am following papers about *parallel association rule mining*, in particular, [this paper](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~paullu/Aurora/Papers/para.assoc.rule.mining.icdm01.pdf).
I do not understand how `conditional FP-Tree` is generated in the paper, specifically in **Table 2** on page 3. I would really appreciate, if anyone could help.